# ad hoc install ios failed | 0x243000 verify_signer_identity

Tags: ios, iphone, ad-hoc-distribution

I am trying to install a iOS app using the ad hoc distribution profile but i am getting the error:

> Notice: 0x243000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app XXXXXX
>
> Error: 0x243000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for    /var/tmp/install_staging.dxFfs8/foo_extracted/Payload/XXXXXX.app/XXXXXX: 0xe8008017
>
> Error: 0x243000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.dxFfs8/foo_extracted/Payload/XXXXXX.app
>
> Error: 0x243000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
>
> Warning: LaunchServices: installation failed for app XXXXXX
>
> Error: 0x243000 handle_install_for_ls: API failed

Does anyone knows what exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

I have gotten almost that exact same error in the following scenario:

I was building an app to be beta tested using an Ad Hoc configuration profile.  I was using a normal developer account, not an Enterprise Developer account.  I created a Certificate, added the beta tester's device, created a new wildcard app ID (*e.g.* com.mycustomer.*), and a new Ad Hoc provisioning profile (of type **Distribution**) that used the Certificate, and checked the beta tester's device.

However, in my Xcode project build settings, if you look under **Code Signing Identity**, I had something like this:

> iOS Distribution (under *Automatic* in the popup)

That wasn't right.  I needed to pick the specific identity that matched the Certificate used when creating the provisioning profile.  In my case, that was something like

> iPhone Distribution: MyCompany, Inc. (M23123JHQ12N) (under *Identities in Keychain* in the popup)

Then, I used Xcode to **Archive**, opened Organizer, clicked the new archive, pressed the **Distribute...** button, chose **Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment**, and made sure the Provisioning Profile was the specific Ad Hoc profile I created for this customer (from MyCompany, Inc. for 'com.mycustomer.*' in popup), and then **Export** to .ipa.

This .ipa could then be dragged to iTunes' app list, and installed.

The key here is the **Code Signing Identity** I was using in my build settings.

### Reference

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html